# Without retention policy or lifecycle rules, would Google Cloud Storage automatically delete files?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My app uses Google Cloud Storage through Firebase with Java, Angular & Flutter. It stores pictures and such there. Now, a lot of older files recently disappeared from Google Cloud Storage. A test version of my app is probably the culprit. But I want to make sure that I got the storage bucket configured correctly.

Please note that I don't have [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) enabled. From what I know, it would keep a copy of deleted files around. That's why I plan to enable it in the **future**. But it doesn't help me with files deleted in the **past**.

Right now, my storage bucket is configured as follows:

- Default storage class: Standard
- Object versioning: Off
- Retention policy: None
- Lifecycle rules: None

So with that configuration, would Google Cloud Storage automatically delete files? Like, say, after a year or so?

Comment: The only case where Google would delete your files without a policy/rule is due to your account being suspended for non-payment. I am assuming that is not an issue in your case.

Comment: That's interesting that you're asking this question now. I am facing exactly the same issue, although my files are not older than an hour. I could not find any logs that would indicate a deletion as well as I have turned off all of the cron workers that take care of cleaning the old files.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for your answer! Yes, non-payment isn't an issue.

Comment: @KarolWojtulewicz Here's what I think happened: I copy my production database into the testing environment. That's a bad idea because the database now points to my live Google files. I think I deleted customers in the test environment that then also wiped the production Google Cloud Storage files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you don't ask Cloud Storage to delete your files, your files will stay around forever. There's no expiration of any sort by default. Cloud Storage is a popular tool for long term storage/backup/retention.

If you want to be especially careful not to delete certain objects, retention policies and object holds can be used to make it harder to delete objects by accident. For example, if you wanted to temporarily ensure that your scripts would not delete your most important object, you could run:

```
gsutil retention temp set gs://my_bucket_name/my_important_file.txt
```

This would set a "temporary object hold" on the object, which would make it so that `my_important_file.txt` could not be deleted with the delete command until you released the hold.

Comment: If you don't pay or if you close your account the files will be deleted!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Non-payment isn't an issue.

Comment: Brandon: I made three changes: Enabled object versioning, changed my code to move files to a "trash" directory instead, and started backups. Yeah, I know, should have done that ages ago. Lesson learnt, I s'pose. 